# tmux: run command in pane and capture result, in bash script

Tags: bash, tmux

Using tmux, I'd like to run a command from one pane against another pane, and capture the output of the command.

For example, say in pane 7 I have an SSH session running, and I'd like to run a bash script in pane 2 to capture the host name from pane 7.

Is this possible?

I know I can do the send keys like so

```
$ tmux send-keys -t 7 "hostname" Enter
```

but I'm not sure how to capture the output from pane 7 into a bash variable.

I don't mind if it displays on the screen either (doesnt have to happen in the background).

EDIT: Note that hostname is just an example - I would like to run other scripts against each pane as well

Comment: Why don't you create a function in your profile which task is to connect to that remote server and get some data? That way you can get specific data about your server no matter which pane you are on.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - `hostname` was just an example, but the general idea is capture the output of running a command in another pane, where ENV variables could be different, different folder, or an SSH session - something capturing output at the tmux pane level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an alternative to `capture-pane` you can similarly use `pipe-pane`. It is often used for logging. You give it a command to pipe all output into, or no command at all to stop piping. So you end up with something like

```
tmux pipe-pane -t 7 'cat >/tmp/capture'
tmux send-keys -t 7 'hostname' Enter
sleep 1
tmux pipe-pane -t 7    # stops piping 
IT=$(</tmp/capture)
```

Beware, this capture includes carriage-return characters. You will need to remove the first and last lines of the capture to get just the wanted output. Eg:

```
IT=$(sed '1d;$d;s/\r//' </tmp/capture)
```

Answer (score 0):

While not exactly what I was looking for, the tmux [capture-pane](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tmux.1.html) command seems to capture the displayed output of a pane, which I can run of course after running my command.

#### example.sh

```
#/bin/bash

# run the command in another pane
tmux send-keys -t 7 "hostname" Enter

# capture it's output
IT=$(tmux capture-pane -p -t 7)
echo "$IT"
```